# Java: Thread safety with StringBuilder

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, stringbuilder

I have a scenario where I want to use `StringBuilder` as a local variable in a method. I understand if `StringBuilder` is a local method variable it should not have any problems about thread-safety.

However, if I append to the `StringBuilder` an instance variable like:

```
class MyClass {
    private List<String> property;

    public void myMethod() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(String s : property) {
            sb.append(s);
        }
    }

    // some other methods that mutate property
}
```

I think to make this thread-safe, simply change the `StringBuilder` to `StringBuffer` is not sufficient. Shall I synchronize on the property itself?

Comment: what is my method doing? seems it's creating a StringBuilder object and throwing it away...

Comment: You need to synchronize the access to the `List`, not the `StringBuilder`

Comment: You probably want to separator between your properties.

Comment: might be interesting: [How do I prove programmatically that StringBuilder is not threadsafe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48558432)

Answer (score 8):

It's not `StringBuilder` but `List<String> property` who is in danger. You have two options:

1. Make `myMethod` and other methods that mutate property `synchronized`
2. Use `java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList` which is thread safe and makes a snapshot for iterator

Comment: Just an FYI for the OP: if you plan on making a lot of updates, be wary of the `CopyOnWriteArrayList` approach; in that case you would be better off going with option 1.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that while you are calling yours `myMethod()`, another thread can be adding new `String` to yours `property` list, thus, modifying the result.

One way to avoid this is using `synchronized` in the methods that access property in any way, or you can use the good old `ReadWriteLock`. The implementation most used is the [`ReentrantReadWriteLock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html). There are good examples in the internet, but what you would do is something like:

```
class MyClass {
    private final ReadWriteLock propertiesLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
    private final Lock read = propertiesLock.readLock();
    private final Lock write = propertiesLock.writeLock();
    ... 

    public StringBuilder myMethod() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        read.lock();
        try {
           // your writing here.
        } finally {
            read.unlock();
        }
        return builder;
    }

    public void addProperty(String property) {
        write.lock();
        try {
            properties.add(property);
        } finally {
            write.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can synchronize on `property`, or on any object, as long as you synchronize on the *same* object in wherever you access `property`.

An alternative to synchronization would be using a thread-safe implementation of `List`, such as `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, which is great (fast, less contention than with synchronization) if the list is read often but not modified too often.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the synchronize issue lies on property.

So just add a synchronization on it:

```
synchronized (property) {
   ...
}
```